# What are the benfits of a premium account?

Tags: world-of-tanks

What are the benefits of buying a premium account for World of Tanks? Does it really make a big difference over playing free to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While technically the only listed benefits are a 50% increase in silver and experience earned per battle that works out in real terms to a significant difference.

As a rule of thumb a premium account effectively doubles your silver income. This is because although it only increase your **income** by 50% your repair costs are not increased resulting in a much higher **profit** per battle.

The increased profit means that you will quickly earn the silver you need for the next tier and by the mid tiers have plenty left over to buy the crew training and modules that increase tank performance. Increased tank performance will result in a better win rate (unless you are lousy at tanks).

Likewise the increased experience will mean that you spend fewer battles with a stock tank and again improve your overall performance rating.

So a premium account does a lot more for you than just increase your income by 50%. It also increases your win rate.

Comment: I'm at tier 3 and got 500.000 silver. Without premium. Not hard to farm silver With 4 - 5 tanks and continues playing by jumping between them u make around 80 - 125k / hour . That is if you start up a new game as soon as you die with another tank. That goes for tier 1 .. Haven't try anything abow tier 3 So you rly don't need premium for the extra 50% silver. If your after stars go for it :)

Answer (score 2):

+50% to earned XP and credits ([link](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Gold_Economy#Premium_Account)).

Earlier only player with premium account could made a platoon of three players and a company, but now it's not necessary (since version 8.5).

*World of Tanks* is Free2Play, not Pay2Win.

Comment: You also get a better garage.

Comment: it is pay2win, but not so much using premium account but by buying gold (and what gold can buy) and vehicles... Of course you can still have fun without spending real money, but you're going end up killed more, and probably stuck in low tiers (longer). The best "stuff" requires gold to buy, which requires a real monetary investment.

Comment: @jwenting premium tanks are weaker than regular of same tier

Comment: @spyder there's a lot of gold only stuff... May well be the premium tanks are weaker, but a lot of course depends on the player as well. And people who pay2win tend to be ones who aren't the greatest players (though in many mmos it's got to the point where you can't win against bad players with US$ gear unless you have US$ gear yourself).

Comment: @jwenting you can buy all premium stuff for credits, except premium tanks and premium account of course

Answer (score 1):

You gain silver and experience faster with a premium account.

When you get to higher tiers, you'll find it's very hard to make money in battles with a free account (around tier 6, I think, depending on how well you play and what tanks you play).  (My chaffee is a level 5 light tank, and typically loses 5000 even with a premium account)

The 50% bonus increase to income means you make money until higher tiers. (No one makes money at tier 10, I believe).

Comment: I make money at tier 10 :) With premium, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your account to premium is, as stated before, a big benefit.
The time you would wait normally to buy a tank once researched is drastically reduced.

Also, Buying a premium tank early on in the game will help you a lot if you already don't have a tier 8 tank for money making (usually the american T8 or the Russian T8 tanks)
As the redit gained on this will boost you past the Tier 3 tanks when researching a line you hadn't researched before. Also this combo is good because you get Free exp faster with a premium tank than with a normal one if you decide to convert the expereince you get on it.